# Why does subversive sometimes try to add files under the bin directory of my project?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

Every once in a while I get an error when committing code to our SVN repo, and this is what it says (I'd show a screenshot but I can't reproduce it):

```
SVN: '0x00400045: Collecting Properties' operation finished with error: 
0x00000014: Resource is inaccessible or it is not under SVN control: 
'C:/Users/blah/dev/big_project/bin/com/meh/package1'.
0x00000014: Resource is inaccessible or it is not under SVN control: 
'C:/Users/blah/dev/big_project/bin/com/meh/package2'.
```

And my commit dialog which shows up after dismissing that shows some (but not all) class files under my bin directory:

[image]

If I do a Project>Clean, (and then it rebuilds automatically) the message goes away for a long while. It seems to happen only after I build the project via an ANT script (which uses javac instead of Eclipse's compiler), but it's not reproducible. As in it'll happen after an ANT build, but not always.

The bin directory is supposed to be ignored. What's going on?

Comment: Is it possible that those files were once under Subversion control, but were deleted? Have you done an `svn update`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error, among others. I don't know what's the cause. The only (desperate) way I could fix them was deleting the project from SVN repository (Delete project through the SNV Perspective in Eclipse and removing manually all the ".svn" hidden folders inside the real path of the project). After that, I was able to commit the project again without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the cause adding `bin` to [svn:ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) should fix it.